# How to calculate a function over cartesian product of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Assume

```
a = np.random.rand(np.random.randint(10), 4)
b = np.random.rand(np.random.randint(10), 4)
```

I would like to vectorize the following:

```
from itertools import product
res = np.array([ious(a[i, :], b) for i in range(a.shape[0])])
```

`ious` can take a vector and a matrix and yield a correct result.

I would like to avoid the list comprehension and be left with pure numpy

I would like a way to trace back which `i,j` gave each result.

If so, How?

---

Edit:

```
class BboxUtils(object):
    @staticmethod
    def ious(bboxes1, bboxes2):
        left1, top1, right1, bottom1 = BboxUtils.bbox_to_perimiters(bboxes1)
        left2, top2, right2, bottom2 = BboxUtils.bbox_to_perimiters(bboxes2)

        area1 = (right1 - left1) * (top1 - bottom1)
        area2 = (right2 - left2) * (top2 - bottom2)

        intersection_left = np.maximum(left1, left2)
        intersection_right = np.minimum(right1, right2)
        intersection_top = np.maximum(top1, top2)
        intersection_bottom = np.minimum(bottom1, bottom2)
        intersection_area = (intersection_right - intersection_left) * (intersection_top - intersection_bottom)
        intersection_area[intersection_area < 0] = 0

        iou = intersection_area / (area1 + area2 - intersection_area)

        return iou

    @staticmethod
    def bbox_to_perimiters(bboxes):
        left, w, top, h = np.split(bboxes.reshape(-1), 4)
        right = left + w
        bottom = top + h
        return left, right, top, bottom
```

I want to cauculate this iou for every possible combination of bboxes.

Comment: I don't get your `i,j` note - there is no `j` in your code.

Comment: `np.arange(3)[:,None]+np.arange(4)` is a 'pure numpy' outer product calculation.  The (3,) array is changed to (3,1), which broadcasts with a (4,) array to produce a (3,4) result.  All the numpy operators work this way, as do most of the `ufunc`.  Learn the broadcasting rules, and these operators/ufunc and you can do a great many things in an optimally `numpy` way.

Comment: Is your goal to learn something or to speed-up calculations that you run on a large datset?

Comment: @rpoleski My dataset will not be large, but I want my code to be optimal. I assume you can regard this as "learn something", just because the speedup will not be critical for me.

Comment: @hpaulj in your case the operator is `+`. What happens with more complicated operations?

Comment: Where possible we try to build the complicated operation from the provided building blocks.